# c++ overload the [] operator for write/set

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have done numerous searches and found a ton of examples and tutorials but still cannot figure out how to get the value when writing to the `[]` operator...

I feel like i'm going insane.  I must be missing something very simple

as far as i can tell there is a single function for `get` and `set` and it looks something like this:

```
V& operator[](string K);
```

or this:

```
double &operator[](int n);
```

---

now great, we can get what is:

```
a[HERE]
```

as `HERE` becomes `double &operator[](int HERE);`
and we can easily work with it

but how do we get what is:

```
a[4] = HERE
```

---

C# has two very clear get and set methods with the value keyword which represents the object being assigned.

```
public string this[int key]
{
    get
    {
        if(key == 1)
           return "1!";
        if(key == 2)
           return "2!";
        else
           return "3!";
    }
    set
    {
        if( value == "setting")   //value is a[3] = THIS
           this.isSet = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't get the right side of an assignment on the return value inside the `operator[]` from which you return that value. You get the right side it when you overload `operator=` on the type of that return value. To illustrate this: `a[5] = HERE` is roughly equivalent to `V& ret = a.operator[](5); ret.operator=(HERE);`

Comment: Well, `a[4] = HERE` means (intuitively, assuming the operator behaves consistently with built-in types) "assign HERE to `a[4]`" (assuming `a` isn't const, and HERE is a macro/variable defined somewhere). What is your question about this ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Overloading the C++ indexing subscript operator \[\] in a manner that allows for responses to updates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3581981/overloading-the-c-indexing-subscript-operator-in-a-manner-that-allows-for-r)

Comment: I was thinking a map scenario.  how would i set a key/value pair like: myMap[key] = value;

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Don't think of `operator[]` as a function to get or set, that might be confusing. Think of it as a normal function. In fact, let's re-write it as a normal function:

```
struct X
{
    int arr[10];
    int& getIndex(int idx) { return arr[idx]; }
};

//...
//initialize x of type X
x.getIndex(3) = 42;
```

The method `x.getIndex(3)` will return a reference to the 4-th element in the member array `idx`. Because you return by reference, the return value is an l-value and refers to that exact element, so you can assign a value to it, say, `42`. This will modify the member `x.arr[3]` as the function returns an alias for that particular object.

Now you can re-write this in terms of `operator[]` exactly as before

```
struct X
{
    int arr[10];
    int& operator[](int idx) { return arr[idx]; }
};
```

and get the same result by calling

```
x[3];
```

or even

```
x.operator[](3);
```

The operator option is just syntactic sugar.

Comment: ok, so it's impossible to do logic inside the [] overload based on the value and the key?

Comment: @EpiX how did you draw that conclusion?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: He's correct, is he not?  The value is not passed to `operator[]`, so how can it operate on it?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: Because x[key] evaluates to a place in memory and then the = value assigns the value to that place in memory.  in x[key] = value

Comment: @BenjaminLindley I don't follow. Which value?

Comment: In the expression: `x[key] = value;`

Comment: @BenjaminLindley I think OP just wants to implement a map and got confused along the way.

Comment: @juanchopanza: Yes, he's trying to re-use his C# idioms in C++, and it won't work. I'm just referring to his comment below this question. And his comment is correct.  In the expression `x[key] = value`, the `operator[]` cannot act based on the value of `value`. At least not in any reasonable way I can think of.  That doesn't mean he can't write code to do what he wants, just that he can't write it the way he wants to, or the way he is used to.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore I think he actually wants to perform operations/logic on the value he wants to assign to the memory referred to by the index. I find this quite counter-intuitive. Operator[] is used (with built-in types, or even `std::map`) to access/write based on an index. Implementing it differently might be confusing (even though you're sure of what you're doing). In this case, "Do as the `int`s do" fits, in my opinion. If it does something completely different that the usual `operator[]`, then writing the `operator[]` might not be the best approach.

Comment: Yeah, I guess it's impossible.  I usually throw simple checks and bounding in there but i guess i'll have to use get/set functions.

Comment: @EpiX: To be clear, you can do any checks you want on the key in `operator[]`, but any checks on the value would have to be taken care of in the assignment operator (`operator=`) of whatever type is returned by your `operator[]`.