# How do I write different operator[] for LValue and RValue?

Tags: c++, operator-keyword, lvalue, rvalue

I am trying to interface a C library to my C++ project. The library has its own vector type, assume to be `VECTOR`, and it provides element access:

```
int vector_set_value(VECTOR* vec, int index, double new_value);
int vector_get_value(VECTOR* vec, int index, double* retrieved_value);
```

Now it would be good to wrap the `get` and `set` operations by operator[] overloading

```
double& operator[](int index);
const double& operator[](int index) const;
```

But how do I tell operator[] have different behavior, between `vec[index]=3` and `double value=vec[3]`? For the prior `vector_set_value` should be called while for the latter `vector_get_value` should be called.

Comment: I know in Ruby there are `def []` and `def []=`, are there any similar strategy in C++?

Comment: use `const double& operator[](int index) const` ?

Comment: Take a look at the [signatures](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at) for `std::vector`'s `operator[]`

Comment: Look at this [query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3581981/overloading-the-c-indexing-subscript-operator-in-a-manner-that-allows-for-r)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not attempt to wrap one interface into the other.

That being said, if you really want to do this one possible solution is to create a proxy object, and have your `operator[]` return that proxy object. The proxy object would have conversions into the underlying type `const double&` for reading, and overloaded `operator=` for writing. Each one of them would call the appropriate library function.

This will allow for syntax that *looks* like that of C++ `std::vector`: `MyVector v(...); v[1] = 10.1; double d = v[1];` but it **will** be problematic. The proxy object cannot replace the real type in all contexts, only in some of them. And even there, the semantics are different, so while it may look like a regular vector, one day you will try to use the proxy in a way it does not support and you will be puzzled at the *[leaking abstraction](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/LeakyAbstractions.html)*

Comment: In particular, you wouldn't be able to pass `vec[3]` to a function expecting a `double &` argument, because the fundamental problem is that the getter-setter interface is incompatible with references.

Comment: I have realized that too because I could not get the address of the `double` variable using that stupid interface. Anyway thank you!