# How do I properly overload the '=' operator to work with an array that is overloading the '[ ]' operator?

Tags: c++, arrays, operator-overloading

I have to write a class, IntArray, that is essentially an array with a few extra features (not shown). I have to utilize operator overloading to assign elements to an array of integers within the IntArray object. My program properly retrieves elements in the array but it cannot assign elements in the array.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class IntArray{
    int *data;
    int SIZE;
    int startIndex;
    int endIndex;
public:
    IntArray(int endI);
    int operator[](int index);
    void operator=(int i);
};

IntArray::IntArray(int endI){
    SIZE = endI;
    data = new int[SIZE];
    endIndex = endI - 1;
    startIndex = 0;
}

int IntArray::operator[](int index){
    if(index > endIndex){
        cout << "Error: Index out of bounds" << endl;
        exit(0);
    }
    return data[index];
}

void IntArray::operator=(int i){
    data[0] = i;
}
```

I assume the problem lies within this function:

```
void IntArray::operator=(int i);
```

Here is my main method:

```
int main(){
    IntArray a(0,1);
    cout << a[0] << endl; //works fine
    a[0] = 3; //does not work
}
```

I am also not sure how to access the array index (the '0' on the 3rd line of main()) from the operator=(int i) function. Thanks for the help!

Comment: _`return data[index - startIndex];`_ Huh???

Comment: I don't think you want to use operator= in the array class.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3581981/overloading-the-c-indexing-subscript-operator-in-a-manner-that-allows-for-r

Comment: Generally it's good to return `IntArray &` by means of `return (*this)`  as well.  And by "Cannot assign" do you mean crash, or do you mean fails to do so?

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ the assignment requires for the IntArray object to have negative indexes. return data[index - startIndex] allows me to convert indexes from negative to where they would be in a normal array. Your question made me realize I didn't supply the code that would explain this.

Comment: @M4rc I mean crash.

Comment: `void IntArray::operator=(int i);` allows you to do `a = 3;`, it has nothing to do with `a[0] = 3;`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> a[0] = 3; //does not work

This cannot compile has nothing to do with `operator=` overload. The problem lies in `int operator[](int index);`

Your `operator[]` overload returns an `int`, so `a[0]` returns an rvalue, and you cannot assign to an rvalue.

The solution is:

`int& operator[](int index);`

In this way, `operator[]` returns a reference (`int&`), which is a lvalue, and you can assign to it.

Comment: you are the real mvp